# Does Core Data's remove<key>Object remove the object from the managed object context?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, accessor

I am curious about the Custom To-Many Relation Accessors.  It makes sense that the accessor will remove related object from the other object.  But I was wondering if you wanted the object completely removed from the managed object context (and subsequently the back store), do you also need to delete the object from the Managed Object Context and then save it?

Thanks for any help!

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rob,

Removing just affects the relationship. You must delete the object to remove it from the MOC and the backing store.

IOW, these are fundamentally different operations.

Andrew

Comment: It made sense to me that they are different, but you just never know.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that there's something called *delete propagation* which may cause objects to get deleted when they're removed from a relationship. C.f. *Relationship Delete Rules* under *Relationships and Fetched Properties* in the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html).